# Copy and Share Google Document to new email but suppress notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have the below code to copy a template and share it with the same people who has access to the template.

However, I have two issues here:

1. I do not want them to receive notification each time a copy is made and shared with them
2. I would also like to share with another person to edit it. The email of the person who can edit is in the google sheet, in column A. This new person should not also receive notificiation.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Create My Checklist');
  menu.addItem('New Checklist', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1qRQ07PDmz1il9IftM9GIJfY37vTusfQZhhNS1BRELJQ');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1JufckhwXlAXDAE3_-f60lHQQ-jqe9Mx1')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  const emailAddresses = googleDocTemplate.getEditors().map(e => e.getEmail()); // Added
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[10]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy("eResignation Checklist - " + row[2] + " - " + row[4] + " - " +  row[5], destinationFolder)
    copy.addEditors(emailAddresses);
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{Workday ID}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Full Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Management Level}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{LoS}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Cost Centre}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{Office Location}}', row[6]);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
   sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url)
  
  Drive.Permissions.insert({role: "writer", type: "user", value: row[0]}, copy.getId(), {sendNotificationEmails: false, supportsAllDrives: true});
  
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to share the copied file.
- The email address for sharing can be retrieved from the column "A".
- When the file is shared, you don't want to send a notification email.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In order to use the option of `sendNotificationEmails`, Drive API is used. So [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

##### From:

```js
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url)
  
})}
```

##### To:

```js
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url)
  
  Drive.Permissions.insert({role: "writer", type: "user", value: row[0]}, copy.getId(), {sendNotificationEmails: false}); // Added
  
})}
```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert)

### Edit:

From the following replying,

> i am really unsure why it says file not found because the copied file is in the shared drive > folder ID: 1JufckhwXlAXDAE3_-f60lHQQ-jqe9Mx1

I noticed that you are using the shared Drive. And from the following replying,

> I have edited the code again as per what I see in my script now. it seems to work partially - for the email in row [0] they are not getting any notification const emailAddresses = googleDocTemplate.getEditors().map(e => e.getEmail()); how to disable notification for this group?

I noticed that your script was changed from your initial script. In this case, please modify as follows.

##### From:

```js
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url)
  
})}
```

##### To:

```js
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url)
  
  emailAddresses.concat(row[0]).forEach(v => 
    Drive.Permissions.insert({role: "writer", type: "user", value: v}, copy.getId(), {sendNotificationEmails: false, supportsAllDrives: true})
  );
  
})}
```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, There are two groups who need edit access to the file:
1) Those who are already in the template (share with the same people)
2) The email address in row [0] - if abc@gmail.com is in cell A2, then the copy should be editable for abc@gmail.com and group #1.

However, I do not want anyone of them to receive notification when the copy is created, since we will only be sending an email with the link to the document at a later time.

I tried adjusting the code as per your suggestion, however, i received an error message that Drive is not defined.

Comment: @Shamie Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your replying. From your question of `The email of the person who can edit is in the google sheet, in column A.`, I understood that you want to use the email for sharing from the column "A". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Shamie And, about `I tried adjusting the code as per your suggestion, however, i received an error message that Drive is not defined.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About my proposed script, I wrote `In order to use the option of sendNotificationEmails, Drive API is used. So please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.` in my answer. From your replying, I thought that you might have still not enabled Drive API. I'm worried that you might not be able to understand my English. If I misunderstood it, I apologize again.

Comment: @Shamie And, I cannot understand `2) The email address in row [0] - if abc@gmail.com is in cell A2, then the copy should be editable for abc@gmail.com and group #1.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, your English is perfectly fine, please dont worry. I believe my lack of knowledge is what confusing me.

I have enabled Google Sheet and Google doc APIs, but I still get this error `ReferenceError: Drive is not definedDetails`.... This line: 

`Const emailAddresses = googleDocTemplate.getEditors().map(e => e.getEmail());`
this is to get the email of those who are in the template and later to share with them. When i share, i dont want them to receive notification.

Then, I want to share with the email in row [0], i also dont want this person to receive notification

Comment: @Shamie Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. I wrote `In order to use the option of sendNotificationEmails, Drive API is used. So please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.`. But in your replying `I have enabled Google Sheet and Google doc APIs, but I still get this error ReferenceError: Drive is not definedDetails`, why did you enable Sheets API and Docs API instead of Drive API? **Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.**

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, I have enabled Drive API, apologies for the confusion. I get the below error. `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: File not found: 1m8JUzS6GbtH--_42edfMkWbj-Dm6DVyDtJFCgJ2vBq0`

Comment: @Shamie Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I have enabled Drive API, apologies for the confusion. I get the below error. GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: File not found: 1m8JUzS6GbtH--_42edfMkWbj-Dm6DVyDtJFCgJ2vBq0 `, in this case, it seems that the file cannot be found. So please check it again. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed modification, no error occurs. I deeply apologize for this situation.

Comment: i am really unsure why it says file not found because the copied file is in the shared drive > folder ID: 1JufckhwXlAXDAE3_-f60lHQQ-jqe9Mx1

Comment: @Shamie Thank you for replying. From `i am really unsure why it says file not found because the copied file is in the shared drive > folder ID: 1JufckhwXlAXDAE3_-f60lHQQ-jqe9Mx1`, I could notice that you are using the shared Drive. I couldn't notice your situation from your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In that case, please modify to `Drive.Permissions.insert({role: "writer", type: "user", value: row[0]}, copy.getId(), {sendNotificationEmails: false, supportsAllDrives: true});` and test it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238528/discussion-between-shamie-and-tanaike).